# I have a html content which is taking the complete width of page but in PDF it is taking only 50% width

Tags: html, pdf, aspose, aspose.pdf

I have a html content which has 100% width and covering the whole screen but when i render the same content in PDF it is just taking 50% width.

```
HtmlLoadOptions objLoadOptions = new HtmlLoadOptions();
objLoadOptions.PageInfo.IsLandscape = true;
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(htmlString));
            Aspose.Pdf.Document doc = new Aspose.Pdf.Document(memoryStream, objLoadOptions);
memoryStream.Dispose();

            doc.ProcessParagraphs();

            double w, h = 0;

            foreach (Page page in doc.Pages)
            {
                w = page.Rect.Width;
                h = page.Rect.Height;
                page.MediaBox = new Rectangle(0, 0, h * h / w, h);
                page.CropBox = new Rectangle(0, 0, h * h / w, h);
            }
```

this is the aspose logic i have written and this is the html content

```
<body style="margin: 0">

<div>

<table style="table-layout: auto; width: 100%;text-align: left;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
</table>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Don't you cause that with your `page.MediaBox` and `page.CropBox` assignments?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with those assignments? Essentially it looks like you want to double the width if the page. The result obviously is that thereafter half the page is empty...

Comment: We have addressed your similar inquiry over Aspose.PDF forums where you posted it. You may please follow up there(https://forum.aspose.com/t/201792/2). This is Asad Ali and I work as Developer Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: @AsadAli thanks for the response. i have tried it out but still i am facing some issue in that. Can you please quickly check and resolve. i will be waiting for the response

Comment: @AdithyaSai According to your comments in respective forum thread over Aspose.PDF forum, it seems your issue has been resolved. Please feel free to let us know in case you face any issue.

Comment: Thank you soo much for the quick response now the issue is resolved